# Making thousands of HTTP requests as fast as possible using python asyncio

Tags: python-3.6, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I need a program that needs to gather data from large list of API end points and do some processing. Below is a mock-up program that attempts to make 10000 requests as fast as possible. Any suggestions on how to improve on this (especially for speed) is highly welcome. Experimentation showed that the Semaphore cap of around 100 gave the best speed.

```
import asyncio
from aiohttp import ClientSession
import datetime
import time
import sys

def processData(data):
    time.sleep(0.001)
    return data

async def fetch(url, session):
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        data = await response.read()
        data = processData(data)
        return data

async def bound_fetch(sem, url, session):
    async with sem:
        return await fetch(url, session)


async def run(loop,N):
    url = "https://www.example.com"
    tasks = []
    sem = asyncio.Semaphore(100)
    async with ClientSession() as session:
        for i in range(N):
            task = loop.create_task(bound_fetch(sem, url, session))
            tasks.append(task)

        print("Done starting {} tasks".format(N))
        starttime = time.time()
        print(datetime.datetime.now())
        responses = await  asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        print("Done completing {} tasks in: {}".format(N,time.time()-starttime))

        return responses



args = sys.argv
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) == 2:
        N = int(sys.argv[1])
    else:
        N = 10000
    maintask = loop.create_task(run(loop, N))
    result = loop.run_until_complete(maintask)
    print(len(result))
```

Comment: Have you profiled the application when it is not fast enough - does it spend time waiting for IO or doing CPU-bound tasks? Have you tried splitting the load to different processes? Are all endpoints on different servers?

Comment: @rajendra sorry, your question is too broad.